# R - Rounding with 'difftime' function

Tags: r, function, time, floating-point

I have this times:
`start.moment <- Sys.time()
end.moment <- Sys.time()`

To know the difference, I do:
`difftime(end.moment, start.moment, units = "mins")`

> Time difference of 0.1501419 mins

But I want a result less extensive, like that (with the same units):

> Time difference of 0.15 mins

What I have to change on last command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `round` to accomplish this:

```
round(difftime(end.moment, start.moment, units = "mins"), 2)
```

or the `signif` the significant number of digits:

```
signif(difftime(end.moment, start.moment, units = "mins"), 2)
```

will also work.

Comment: I was thinking I could use `format` parameter,.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a part of `print.difftime(...)`, which is implicitly called every time you want to see the result of a `difftime` operation.

```
print(end.moment - start.moment, digits = 2)
Time difference of 15 mins
```

Comment: Thus I got something like (with 3 digits): `Time difference of 1.46e+09`